# How to get transparent nodata values in GeoExplorer?

Tags: raster, geoexplorer

I have a single-band raster image with NoData values set to 0. Is it possible to get them transparent in GeoExplorer?

Comment: This link describes how to do it in [**GeoServer**](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Trying-to-get-nodata-in-GeoTIFF-to-display-as-transparent-td3853784.html). Perhaps you can then import the raster into **GeoExplorer**...?